# TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class when using langchain in azure

Tags: python, azure, pip, python-venv, langchain

I have a simple python app with streamlit and langchain, I am deploying this to Azure via CI/CD with the following YAML definition

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup streamlit
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'
        
          - task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
            displayName: 'Set App Settings'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'AzureAIPocPrincipal'
              appName: 'test'
              resourceGroupName: 'AzureAIPoc'
              appSettings: |
                [
                  {
                    "name": "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD",
                    "value": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
                    "value": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "POST_BUILD_COMMAND",
                    "value": "pip install -r ./requirements.txt"
                  }
                ]

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : {{ webAppName }}'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'AzureAIPocPrincipal'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              deployToSlotOrASE: true
              resourceGroupName: 'AzureAIPoc'
              slotName: 'production'
              appName: 'test'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              startUpCommand: 'python -m streamlit run app/home.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0'
```

My requirements file is:

```
langchain==0.0.225
streamlit
openai
python-dotenv
pinecone-client
streamlit-chat
chromadb
tiktoken
pymssql
typing-inspect==0.8.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
Traceback:
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/app/pages/xxv0.2.py", line 6, in <module>
    import langchain
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from langchain.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/agents/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.agents.agent import (
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 26, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.base import Chain
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.api.base import APIChain
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/api/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.api.prompt import API_RESPONSE_PROMPT, API_URL_PROMPT
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/api/prompt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/prompts/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.example_selector import (
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/prompts/example_selector/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.example_selector.semantic_similarity import (
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/prompts/example_selector/semantic_similarity.py", line 8, in <module>
    from langchain.embeddings.base import Embeddings
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/embeddings/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from langchain.embeddings.sagemaker_endpoint import SagemakerEndpointEmbeddings
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/embeddings/sagemaker_endpoint.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain.llms.sagemaker_endpoint import ContentHandlerBase
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/llms/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from langchain.llms.vertexai import VertexAI
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/llms/vertexai.py", line 14, in <module>
    from langchain.utilities.vertexai import (
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/utilities/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from langchain.utilities.apify import ApifyWrapper
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/utilities/apify.py", line 5, in <module>
    from langchain.document_loaders import ApifyDatasetLoader
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from langchain.document_loaders.embaas import EmbaasBlobLoader, EmbaasLoader
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/embaas.py", line 54, in <module>
    class BaseEmbaasLoader(BaseModel):
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 204, in __new__
    fields[ann_name] = ModelField.infer(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 488, in infer
    return cls(
           ^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 419, in __init__
    self.prepare()
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 539, in prepare
    self.populate_validators()
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 801, in populate_validators
    *(get_validators() if get_validators else list(find_validators(self.type_, self.model_config))),
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/validators.py", line 696, in find_validators
    yield make_typeddict_validator(type_, config)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/validators.py", line 585, in make_typeddict_validator
    TypedDictModel = create_model_from_typeddict(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/annotated_types.py", line 35, in create_model_from_typeddict
    return create_model(typeddict_cls.__name__, **kwargs, **field_definitions)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 972, in create_model
    return type(__model_name, __base__, namespace)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 204, in __new__
    fields[ann_name] = ModelField.infer(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 488, in infer
    return cls(
           ^^^^
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 419, in __init__
    self.prepare()
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 534, in prepare
    self._type_analysis()
File "/tmp/8db82251b0e58bc/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py", line 638, in _type_analysis
    elif issubclass(origin, Tuple):  # type: ignore
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/typing.py", line 1570, in __subclasscheck__
    return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am not copying here the app script as the code works locally, I think its something more related to Azure App Service Plan Environment or the venv setup in the yaml file.